# How to put Gson value into HashMap

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database and I want to store users information in my app. In my firebase database, I have 4 string and 1 arraylist like this..

[image: User's values]

I want to store these values in my app with using SharedPreferences. I did retrieve Phone number, Birthdate, First name and Gender and I stored into a Hashmap. But I couldn't get User hobbies. I use Gson library for User hobbies, but I don't know how to use with other string values.

```
public static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_BIRTHDATE = "birthdate";
public static final String KEY_GENDER = "gender";
public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
public static final String KEY_HOBBIES = "hobbies";

public SessionManager(Context _context) {
    context = _context;
    usersSession = _context.getSharedPreferences("userLoginSession", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = usersSession.edit();
}

public void createLoginSession(String name, String birthdate, String gender, String phone, ArrayList<String> hobby) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(hobby);

    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

    editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
    editor.putString(KEY_BIRTHDATE, birthdate);
    editor.putString(KEY_GENDER, gender);
    editor.putString(KEY_PHONE, phone);

    editor.putString(KEY_HOBBIES, json);


    editor.commit();

}

public HashMap<String, String> getUsersDetailFromSession() {
    HashMap<String, String> userData = new HashMap<String, String>();

    userData.put(KEY_NAME, usersSession.getString(KEY_NAME, null));
    userData.put(KEY_BIRTHDATE, usersSession.getString(KEY_BIRTHDATE, null));
    userData.put(KEY_GENDER, usersSession.getString(KEY_GENDER, null));
    userData.put(KEY_PHONE, usersSession.getString(KEY_PHONE, null));

    return userData;
}
```

In createLoginSession, I defined a gson variable and I used putString value to KEY_HOBBIES like other strings. **What should I do to put User Hobbies with other strings in Hashmap function? I want to load and read all datas in Hashmap.** *My english is not very good, thank you for all.*

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but are you saying that you don't know how to get user_Hobbies from firebase database ?

Comment: @LaurentiuDaniel yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jsonArray like this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("response");
                    for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                         //here you use your objects
}
```

Comment: Can I add Json array into my Hashmap function with other string values?

Comment: Yes of course You can add json array using nested loop